# .net Maui binding values multiple levels deep

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

How can I Pass a Binding from a `Page` to a `View`?

I have this Page(Xaml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:DataBindingTests.Views"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:DataBindingTests.ViewModels"
             x:Class="DataBindingTests.Pages.CoolePage"
             Title="CoolePage"
             x:DataType="model:CoolesModel">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding YourName}"></Label>
        <views:MainView YourName="{Binding YourName}"></views:MainView>
        <Button Command="{Binding ChangeNameCommand}"></Button>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

And its CodeBehind:

```
using DataBindingTests.ViewModels;

namespace DataBindingTests.Pages;

public partial class CoolePage : ContentPage
{
    public CoolePage()
    {
        this.BindingContext = new CoolesModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

If I pass a String into my MainView it works and all events are fired. When I use the binding it doesn't. In this simple test, the app should display two times the same name, but only the Label of the ContentPage has the `YourName` property printed

<views:MainView YourName="Lars"></views:MainView> **<-- Works**

<views:MainView YourName="{Binding YourName}"></views:MainView> **<-- doesn't work**

**This is the Xaml of the MainView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:DataBindingTests.Views"
             x:Class="DataBindingTests.Views.MainView">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding YourName}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

**This is the CodeBehind of the MainView**

```
namespace DataBindingTests.Views;

public partial class MainView : ContentView
{
    public String YourName
    {
        get
        {
            String value = (String)GetValue(MainView.YourNameProperty);
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MainView.YourNameProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty YourNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(YourName)
    , typeof(String)
    , typeof(MainView), defaultBindingMode:BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnYourNameChanged);

    static void OnYourNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(newValue);
    }

    public MainView()
    {
        this.BindingContext = this; // Ignore ParentContext
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove code `this.BindingContext = this;` from the constructor of `MainView.xaml.cs`:

```
 public MainView()
    {
        //this.BindingContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

**Update:**

> the above code would only work because the Property in the View and
> the Page have the same name.

In this condition, you can modify the code of `MainView.xaml` as follows:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp929.MainView"
             x:Name="TestControlView"
             >
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label   Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference TestControlView}, Path=YourName}"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

MainView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainView : ContentView 
{

    public String YourName
    {
        get
        {
            String value = (String)GetValue(YourNameProperty);
            return value;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(YourNameProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty YourNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(YourName)
    , typeof(String)
    , typeof(MainView), defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay, propertyChanged: OnYourNameChanged);

    static void OnYourNameChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------> "+newValue);
    }
    public MainView()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

       // this.BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

CoolesModel.cs

```
public class CoolesModel 
{
    //  public string YourName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string TestName { get; set; }

    public ICommand ChangeNameCommand => new Command(changeMethod);

    private void changeMethod()
    {

    }

    public CoolesModel() {
        //YourName = "abc";
        Name = "abc";

        TestName = "test123...";
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:mauiapp929="clr-namespace:MauiApp929"
             x:Class="MauiApp929.MainPage">
  
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout>
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"></Label>
            <mauiapp929:MainView YourName="{Binding TestName}"></mauiapp929:MainView>
            <Button Command="{Binding ChangeNameCommand}"></Button>
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: But then it would be bound to the complete data context of the parent wouldn't it?

Comment: Furthermore, if I had a ViewModel in my MainView and would still want to use the BindableProperty, it wouldn't work either. If I remove "this.BindingContext = this;", the above code would only work because the Property in the View and the Page have the same name.

Comment: I have updated my reply. You can check the updated part of my answer.

Comment: That makes it much clearer. My context needs to be bound to the parent, but I can refer to the views variables itself.

Answer (score 0):

> In this simple test, the app should display two times the same name, but only the Label of the ContentPage has the YourName property printed

You're overwriting your binding context half way through for some reason, and the context your page binding resolves (the normal way of using it, the parent context) is different than what you actually see on the screen (which is your `this.BindingContext = this`). And you never set your second context's property.

Comment: "this.BindingContext = this" is simply used so that I don't access the Properties of the parent's context. If I would access the parent's context, then setting the Binding on the Page would be useless from my point of view

Comment: Quite true, doing view models correctly leads to much cleaner code with no repetitions.