# Pass a Binding into Reusable UI Element in MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I'm trying to create a reusable ContentView that can be bound to an instance specific value. The view is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:element="clr-namespace:SimultaneousEquations.Elements"
             x:Class="SimultaneousEquations.Elements.EquationElement">

    <ContentView.BindingContext>
        <element:EquationElement />
    </ContentView.BindingContext>

    <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Label FontSize="22" Text="{Binding EquationAsString}"  HorizontalOptions="Center" /> 
        <Label>
            <Label.Margin>8,0,0,0</Label.Margin>
        </Label>
        <Frame 
                WidthRequest="30" 
                HeightRequest="30" 
                CornerRadius="15"
                BorderColor="Black" 
                Padding="0" >
            <Label 
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                    Text="1"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    FontSize="22" >
            </Label>
        </Frame>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
    
</ContentView>
```

Code Behind:

```
namespace SimultaneousEquations.Elements;

public partial class EquationElement : ContentView
{
    public EquationElement()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string EquationAsString
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(EquationAsStringProperty);
        set => SetValue(EquationAsStringProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty EquationAsStringProperty =
           BindableProperty.Create(
               nameof(EquationAsString),
               typeof(string),
               typeof(EquationElement),
               "Equation Not Set"//string.Empty
               );
}
```

I'm then trying to use it in a ContentPage. Using the Reusable elements causes the app to crash. Using similar code directly in the view works fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:SimultaneousEquations.ViewModels"
             xmlns:elements="clr-namespace:SimultaneousEquations.Elements"
             x:Class="SimultaneousEquations.Views.SolveView"
             Title="Solver">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:SolveViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <VerticalStackLayout>

        <!-- THIS CAUSES APP TO CRASH AT LAUNCH -->
        <elements:EquationElement EquationAsString="{Binding FirstEquation.AsString}"/>

        <!-- THIS WORKS -->
        <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Label FontSize="22" Text="{Binding FirstEquation.AsString}"  HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            <Label><Label.Margin>8,0,0,0</Label.Margin></Label>
            <Frame 
                WidthRequest="30" 
                HeightRequest="30" 
                CornerRadius="15"
                BorderColor="Black" 
                Padding="0" >
                <Label 
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                    Text="1"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    FontSize="22" >
                </Label>
            </Frame>
        </HorizontalStackLayout>

        <Button  HorizontalOptions="Center"  Text="Solve" Command="{Binding SolveCommand}" />

    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Please can somebody help me get this to work. Thanks

EDIT: On android, the app just crashes without exception. I tried re-running the code that crashed in a WindowsMachine and got an exception in an auto-generated code file called Elements_EquationElement.xaml.sg.cs. The exception hit here:

```
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            global::Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(EquationElement));
        }
```

The message said Exception Unhandled - System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception_WasThrown'

I'm not sure that this appears very helpful.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: You'll need to add bindable properties to your code behind. Show the code behind of your UI so that someone can show you how to implement it. You cannot do it just using XAML.

Comment: I've added my ViewModel which my elements bind to. Hopefully this helps with an answer

Comment: *'I don't have a code behind on the view"* That won't work. There must ALWAYS be code behind, because the view constructor must call `InitializeComponent();`. Start over. Do **Project / Add Item / ContentVIew**, to get the **two files** you need. Then edit them.

Comment: Well yeah, I have that minimal initialisation. Just no other code in there. I need to be able to tell the reusable view element what variable it should bind to instead of the hard coded binding shown above

Comment: @Jason, that link you sent me above looks very promising but I still can't figure out how to use the Bindable Property in my reusable view element. Some help would be appreciated

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73691579/binding-not-working-on-custom-bindableproperty

Comment: @Jason Thanks for that - I've reframed my question based on changes I've made from the linked question - I think I'm almost there cut the code currently crashes the app on launch. Can you help put me right? Thanks

Comment: What exception causes the crash!  What line causes the exception?  What does the stack trace show?

Comment: It doesnt seem to throw an exception. The app starts to launch in the android emulator and then just quits. No errors/warnings from the build. There's 188 lines in the output but no obvious issue. Final line is: [libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x5 in tid 9780 (aneousequations), pid 9780 (aneousequations)

Comment: I've tried re-running it on a WindowsMachine and got a weird exception. I'll post it in the question

Comment: Your ContentView is recursively binding to itself

Comment: If I remove the ContentView.BindingContext from EquationElement the app doesn't crash but the value I'm trying to bind also doesn't display

Comment: Try setting `BindingContext = this` one the constructor

Comment: With BindingContext = this, I get the default "Equation Not Set" text appearing.

Comment: please post your entire solution somewhere so I can download it.  Debugging this via an endless stream of comments in tiresome

Comment: I really appreciate the help Jason. Can you get the project from my dropbox here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uwsmwgd956oi0h9/SimultaneousEquations.7z?dl=0

Comment: Nevermind - got it working in the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change I needed to make this work was to change the way I set up the Binding in the reusable ContentView, with a Binding Source and Path, like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:element="clr-namespace:SimultaneousEquations.Elements"
             x:Class="SimultaneousEquations.Elements.EquationElement"
             x:Name="ControlView">

    <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Label FontSize="22" 
               Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference ControlView}, Path=EquationAsString}" 
               HorizontalOptions="Center" /> 
        <Label>
            <Label.Margin>8,0,0,0</Label.Margin>
        </Label>
        <Frame 
                WidthRequest="30" 
                HeightRequest="30" 
                CornerRadius="15"
                BorderColor="Black" 
                Padding="0" >
            <Label 
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference ControlView}, Path=EquationNumber}"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    FontSize="22" >
            </Label>
        </Frame>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
    
</ContentView>
```

This example really helped me: [.net Maui binding values multiple levels deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73886008/net-maui-binding-values-multiple-levels-deep)